# Koha 3.14 - Zebra search is not working

Tags: perl, search

I ran the indexing in Koha,
My out file contents are as follows:

```
Zebra configuration information

Zebra biblio directory      = /opt/koha-3.14.04/conf/var/lib/zebradb/biblios
Zebra authorities directory = /opt/koha-3.14.04/conf/var/lib/zebradb/authorities
Koha directory              = /opt/koha-3.14.04
BIBLIONUMBER in :     999$c
BIBLIOITEMNUMBER in : 999$d

skipping authorities


exporting biblio


1........
Records exported: 9


REINDEXING zebra


16:30:33-25/04 zebraidx(7778) [warn] No such record type: dom./opt/koha-3.14.04/conf/etc/zebradb/biblios/etc/dom-config.xml
```

CLEANING

When I perform a search, I get no results.

The logs give me this:

[image: Log results]

Kindly advice, Where should I look and how should I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the [tag:perl] tag?

Comment: @Miller Because koha is associated with perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this reply from the Koha mailing list: A guy called Nick helped me:

Check if you've got the directory

/usr/lib/idzebra-2.0/modules

or the directory

/usr/lib64/idzebra-2.0/modules

on your server. Chances are it'll be the second option. If so, edit these four files
          /etc/koha/zebradb/zebra-authorities.cfg
          /etc/koha/zebradb/zebra-authorities-dom.cfg
          /etc/koha/zebradb/zebra-biblios.cfg
          /etc/koha/zebradb/zebra-biblios-dom.cfg
In each, change the line reading:
         modulePath: /usr/lib/idzebra-2.0/modules
to
         modulePath: /usr/lib64/idzebra-2.0/modules

And then try reindexing your records.

You could also try using the -x switch when reindexing....

I suppose there should be a bug filed for the incorrect module path on 64bit machines when installed via the tarball. I know that it is among the patches I apply manually whenever I upgrade a system. (Gave me no end of grief the first time)

Comment: PS: This solution will work where the problem is path related, mostly on 64 bit machines.